# ob_start gets interrupted when error occur

Tags: php, buffer

So `ob_start()` is supposed to capture output until another buffer function is called like `ob_get_clean()`, `ob_get_contents()`, `ob_get_flush()`.

But when an exception is thrown inside the buffer reader it will effect the reader by stopping it and echo the output instead of keep capturing it. This is what I want to prevent.

Lets say this is my script:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    try {
        ob_start();
            echo "I don't wanna output this what so ever, so want to cache it in a variable with using ob_ functions";
            $unlink = unlink('some file that does not exist');
            if(!$unlink) throw new Exception('Something really bad happen.', E_ERROR); //throwing this exception will effect the buffer
        $output = ob_get_clean();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "<br />Some error occured: " . $e->getMessage();
        //print_r($e);
    }
?>
```

This script will output:

```
I don't wanna output this what so ever, so want to cache it in a variable with using ob_ functions
Some error occurred: Something really bad happen.
```

When it's suppose to just print

```
Some error occurred: Something really bad happen.
```

What am I doing wrong, is there a solution?

Comment: Try moving `ob_start()` outside of the `try...catch` block.

Comment: @vinodadhikary Thanks for the comment, that could work but will result in the error message getting buffered too. I don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that even inside your catch block, output buffering is still active. However, the script ends with active output buffering, so PHP automatically shows the output buffer.

So you can try to call `ob_clean()` inside your exception handler.

Comment: you are absolutely right, i can't believe i didn't think of that! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    $currentBuffers = '';
    try {
        ob_start();
        echo "I don't wanna output this what so ever, so want to cache it in a variable with using ob_ functions";
        $unlink = unlink('some file that does not exist');
        if(!$unlink) throw new Exception('Something really bad happen.', E_ERROR); //throwing this exception will effect the buffer
        $output = ob_get_clean();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $currentBuffers = ob_get_clean();
        ob_end_clean(); // Let's end and clear ob...
        echo "<br />Some error occured: " . $e->getMessage();
        //print_r($e);
    }

    // Do something to $currentBuffer

    // Maybe start again?
    ob_start();
    echo "foo";
    $currentBuffers .= ob_get_clean();
    //echo $currentBuffers;
        ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to put in my two cents for anyone who stumbles across it in the future.

I had the problem that the cache was not cleared despite catching the exception. it was printed anyway.

For me the solution was to add an additional catch block for catching throwables:

```
try
{
    ob_start();
        // some stuff
    ob_end_clean(); // or any other function
}
catch (\Throwable $e)
{
    ob_end_clean();
    throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
} 
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    ob_end_clean();
    throw $e;
}
```

since an exception is a throwable, the second catch block is not mandatory but I added it to be sure